# Why Text Cells converted with Alt-7 have different fonts

Tags: front-end, formatting, cells, fonts

So I am writing a report in Mathematica and experiencing a problem.

First I create an input cell. Then write some text into it. Afterwards convert it to text cell with Alt-7. As a result some cells show up as the first cell, some as the second (as shown in the gif below).

[image]

As you can see in the gif, the cell fonts are different.
Also the cell brackets are different. However both cells were created using **Format > Style > Text (Alt-7 shortcut)**.

Here is the question. Why is this happening and how can I make them look the same way (use the same fonts at least)?

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: The cell brackets give a clue.  One is an output cell, the other a text cell.  I guess that you have generated output using Mathematica then edited it.  I don't think this is likely to work very well.

Comment: How can I convert the output cell into text cell. No output was generated. cells behave differently when I convert their style into text.

Comment: @Levon Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You input cell contained a `SubscriptBox` so it can't be converted to a string when switching to a Text cell. The whole cell content is left as it was in `BoxData` which makes `StandardForm` styles active with addition to "Text" cell styles. The second cell content can be converted to a plain string so only "Text" styles apply.

You can investigate the content with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

To keep consistent fonts, with Text cells and with 2D typesetting features proceed as follows:

- **do not convert input cells** but write in text cells from the beginning
- when a 2D formula happens, e.g. a subscript entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, **an *inline cell* will be created automatically** leaving the rest of the cell intact while supporting 2D features "locally"
- in the second cell your `τ` should match the previous one, you can select it and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> **to create an inline cell manually**.

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks @Kuba